# How to run multi module maven application?

Tags: java, maven, module, dependencies, maven-module

I tried to run my multi module maven application with

```
mvn -f pom.xml -DskipTests clean install
java -jar modules/mainmodule/target/mainmodule-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The build works without problems and all modules are available in my .m2 repository, but when running the application I get that error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/peyrer/indexmodule/Indexmodule
```

This isn't the only dependency java can't find, it can't find any dependency.
To me it seems that java can`t find my local maven repository. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In a jar there are no dependencies contained. Only if you make it explicit and creating a called ueber-jar or executable jar via maven-assembly-plugin/maven-shade-plugin ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NoClassDefFoundError` error occurs when the class on which your application depends is not available when executing code.

Perhaps this happens because you have not added dependencies of your maven project to the jar file.

Try to use maven-assembly-plugin.

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <!-- any other plugins -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```